# iOS/Xcode: How to simulate network connection between two iOS simulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, network-programming, ios-simulator

I wanna build an app that communicates with other devices through the wifi network. As I don't have two real iOS devices I'd like to connect two iOS Simulators in a virtual network. At first I don't know how/whether it is possible to run two simulators at the same time and secondly I don't know how to manage this network stuff.
It would also be a possibility to connect my real iPhone to the simulated one.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Regards Nils

Comment: You can't run two simulators on the same Mac, but as long as your Mac and your iPhone are on the same network then you can test

Comment: Ok thanks. Is the IP address of the simulator the same as the one of my mac? I've not yet programmed my app but I've tried to use AirDrop between my the iPhone and the simulator which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered it on another question, please check the below procedure to launch multiple simulators

Yes you can do that but there is a limitation in it, you cant debug the log of all the devices simultaneously.
To do that first of all run the app on all the simulator on which you want to test your app, then in the command prompt, hit this link

> cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications

After that hit the below command, this will start new simulator whenever you hit this command.

> open -n iOS\ Simulator.app

Just press ok on Unable to boot device in current state: Booted Pop up.
After that go to hardware>>devices select the device in which you want to test the app, then manually launch the app in each device.
After this you will be able to test your app in all the simulators.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you that's a great way to do. But how do the simulators actually deal with IP addresses? Is there a way to find out the (virtual) internal IP addresses of the simulators?

Comment: Our simulators are connected on same network, as you are running them on the same system.

Comment: Yes of course. But in order to communicate manually I gotta know the IP addresses, don't I?

Comment: The IP address of all your simulators are same(as that of your system). As all the simulators will use the same network which is used by the system.

Comment: Ok I'll try later on. I think I gotta learn more about Networking at first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For newer Xcode Versions (14) you can build and run the app on, let‘s say iPhone 14, then go to Debug > Detach from <>. Then choose another target like iPhone 14 Pro and build and run again. This should open up two simulators. Keep in mind that only the latest build will have console output.